# Need a regular expression for this : Baby[Boy"|"Girl"][A-Z]

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for the above expression. For Example

Baby Boy A, Baby Girl B.

Comment: What regex(es) did you try so far? What language/tool is this for?

Comment: Also please give sample inputs and identify what you want matched.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex:

```
Baby (?:Boy|Girl) [A-Z]
```

Here `Boy` and `Girl` are or'ed using `|`. And using `?:` the group capture is ignored.

You can use `(?i)` [if its supported by your regex engine] at the beginning of the regex to make it case insensitive.

```
(?i)Baby (?:Boy|Girl) [A-Z]
```

You can also [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the regex using `^` and `$` to match the whole string.

Comment: The `(?i)` syntax is not valid in all regex flavors for case-insensitivity. For instance, it does not work in JavaScript. It's difficult, if not impossible, to give an exact regex without knowing OP's context for the regex.

Comment: Thanks @ajp15243. I have updated my answer, and mentioned that [if its supported by regex engine].